# Difficulties in using `gathered`

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\begin{document}

We say that a $d$-tuple $\mathbf{T}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d$ has the $A$-convex property $(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}})$ if:
 \begin{itemize}
  \item $\forall\,\lambda=\langle \mathbf{T} x\mid x\rangle_A,\;\mu=\langle \mathbf{T} y\mid y\rangle_A\in JtW_A(\mathbf{T})
  \,\text{with}\,\|x\|_A=\|y\|_A=1,$
  \item $\forall\,\eta\in[\lambda\mu]$
     \end{itemize}
   $$\Downarrow$$
     \begin{gather*}
    \exists\,\alpha,\,\beta\in \mathbb{C} \;\text{such that}\;\{
   \begin{gathered}
    \|\alpha x+\beta y\|_A=1\\\text{and}\\
    \langle \mathbf{T} (\alpha x+\beta y)\mid \alpha x+\beta 
   y\rangle_A=\eta.
   \end{gathered}
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

I'm facing difficulties to obtain as the picture shows

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose these two variants. The first uses the `empheq` package (which loads `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

We say that a $d$-tuple $\mathbf{T}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d$ has the $A$-convex property $(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}})$ if:
 \begin{itemize}
  \item $\forall\,\lambda=\langle \mathbf{T} x\mid x\rangle_A,\;\mu=\langle \mathbf{T} y\mid y\rangle_A\in JtW_A(\mathbf{T})
  \,\text{with}\,\|x\|_A=\|y\|_A=1,$
  \item $\forall\,\eta\in[\lambda\mu]$
     \end{itemize}
   \[ \Downarrow \]
     \begin{empheq}[left ={ \exists\,\alpha,\,\beta\in \mathbb{C} \;\text{such that}\;\empheqlbrace}]{gather*}
    \|\alpha x+\beta y\|_A=1\\\text{and}\\
    \langle \mathbf{T} (\alpha x+\beta y)\mid \alpha x+\beta
   y\rangle_A=\eta.
    \end{empheq}
\vskip 2cm
 \begin{itemize}
  \item $\forall\,\lambda=\langle \mathbf{T} x\mid x\rangle_A,\;\mu=\langle \mathbf{T} y\mid y\rangle_A\in JtW_A(\mathbf{T})
  \,\text{with}\,\|x\|_A=\|y\|_A=1,$
  \item $\forall\,\eta\in[\lambda\mu]$
     \end{itemize}
     \begin{gather*}
     \Downarrow \\
    \exists\,\alpha,\,\beta\in \mathbb{C} \;\text{such that}\;
   \begin{cases*}
    \|\alpha x+\beta y\|_A=1\\ & \text{and}\\
    \langle \mathbf{T} (\alpha x+\beta y)\mid \alpha x+\beta
   y\rangle_A=\eta.
   \end{cases*}
    \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please can I delete `\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}` or these packages are necessary?

Comment: `amsmath` is loaded by `mathtools`, `empheq` and `nccmath`, so, as soon as you load one of these, you may delete loading amsmath. Similarly, `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so the former is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `gathered` environment here; instead, consider using a `cases` environment.

I would also like to propose that you omit the `\Downarrow` part and streamline the overall structure of the second bullet-point item.

Note that either way, the displayed math part belongs to the `\item`. Hence, `\end{itemize}` should occur only after the cases are stated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, xcolor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}

\noindent {\color{red} before streamlining}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\forall\,\eta\in[\lambda\mu]$
\begin{gather*}
\Downarrow\\
\exists\ \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}
\text{ such that }
\begin{cases}
\|\alpha x+\beta y\|_A=1 \text{ and}\\
\langle \mathbf{T} (\alpha x+\beta y)\mid 
\alpha x +\beta y\rangle_{A}=\eta\,.
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
\end{itemize}
\noindent {\color{red} after streamlining}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\forall\,\eta\in[\lambda\mu]\ \exists\ \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}$ such that 
\[
\begin{cases}
\norm{\alpha x+\beta y}_A=1 \text{ and}\\
\langle \mathbf{T} (\alpha x+\beta y)\mid 
\alpha x +\beta y\rangle^{}_{\!A}=\eta\,.
\end{cases}
\]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my presentation if I want to add a pause afer `such that`, is it correct to add `\uncover<6>{\begin{cases}
\|\alpha x+\beta y\|_A=1 \text{ and}\\
\langle \mathbf{T} (\alpha x+\beta y)\mid
\alpha x +\beta y\rangle_{A}=\eta\,.
\end{cases}}` ?

Comment: @Schüler - To answer your follow-up question, more contextual information is needed. May I ask you that you post a new query, in which you provide the needed information?

Comment: Thank you. But I just want to add pause and when I used `\uncover<6>{..}` it works fine. However I don't know if it is a good method or not to add pause.